# Find a text string and return data from same row with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a macro code that is going to find a text string from a certain cell within a range of cells in a worksheet, and return data from the same row and print out all the matched row in another work sheet. I was using an array formula to do that in cell, but it turned out to be very slow and of bad architecture.

Let's say, I wanna find A2 from sheet2 in sheet1 within the range of E2:F20, and print out data from A to D from the same row in sheet3.

Now based on gary's student's answer, I came up with something like this,however, it still doesn't work.

```
Sub Macro1()


Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
Dim rw1 As Long

Set r2 = Sheets("Committees").Range("A2")
Set r1 = Sheets("Database").Range("P2:CO5000")
Set r3 = Sheets("Reports").Range("F2")

Set rw1 = r1.Find(What:=r2.Value, After:=r1(1)).Row
If Not rw1 Is Nothing Then
   Do Until rw1 Is Nothing
      Sheets("Database").Range("A" & rw1 & ":O" & rw1).Copy r3
      Set rw1 = .FindNext(rw1)
   Loop
End If
Set rw1 = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

How should I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this related to your last question? Please show your code.

Comment: Please show what you have, and some sample data as well. I *think* an Index/Match could work for you, but can you clarify how the data is laid out?

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, I was using a INDEX/MATCH formula in the cell, and it takes too long to run since I have thousands of cells. So the solution would be using some sort of loop in VBA. The data layout it like I have 20 rows and 6 columns of data, and I wanna find a certain text string in the the last two columns and now I want it to return the data from the first four columns in the same row.

Comment: Where in *Sheet3* ??

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the MATCH result in a (potentially) hidden column first and reference that in the INDEX formulas that need the same MATCH value?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, sheet3 is just where I wanna print out the contents.

Comment: But **WHERE** in *Sheet3* should the contents be printed ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, at cell F2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample:

```
Sub FindAndMove()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Dim rw1 As Long

    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:F20")
    Set r3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F2")

    rw1 = r1.Find(What:=r2.Value, After:=r1(1)).Row

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rw1 & ":D" & rw1).Copy r3

End Sub
```

where `r2` holds the data to be found.
Where `r1` is the area to be searched.
Where `r3` is the destination of the data.

Comment: thank you so much for repsonding so quickly, but in this way, it only returns the first ob.

Comment: @JosephLin Nothing in the question to indicate that more than one was needed.